# UTF8String giving different value for same string objective-c

Tags: objective-c, utf-8, nsstring

I am matching strings in condition. Both strings are exactly same.I also *trimmed all whitespace and newline characters*. But compiler saying both are not same.

I investigate a lot then I identify that both strings have `UTF8String` value as different.

```
po otherPersonName
"76000 13590"

po [otherPersonName UTF8String]
"76000 13590"


po findPersonName
"76000 13590"

po [findPersonName UTF8String]
    "\xffffffc2\xffffffa076000\xffffffc2\xffffffa013590\xffffffe2\xffffff80\xffffffac"
```

Can I anyone explain what to do match correctly this strings.

Comment: Basically, `findPersonName` *isn't* the same as `otherPersonName` - it contains a bunch of unprintable characters, by the looks of it. What happens if you look at the length of `findPersonName`?

Comment: What do you recommend to remove this unprintable characters in a string? As both strings are generated by my coding itself only. @JonSkeet

Comment: Then it sounds like there's a bug in your string generation code. Don't remove them - avoid them being created in the first place.

Comment: @JonSkeet I am simply reading a text file using NSUTF8StringEncoding to produce that string?

Answer (score 0):

In `findPersonName` there are non-breaking spaces (U+00A0, UTF-8 C2 A0, which po is showing as `\xffffffc2\xffffffa0`) at the start and between the numbers, and a POP DIRECTIONAL FORMATTING (U+202C, UTF-8 E2 80 AC, `\xffffffe2\xffffff80\xffffffac`) at the end (suggesting the value has come from a larger text with mixed scripts, left-to-right and right-to-left).

If these are the *only* characters that might occur a couple of calls to `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:` may be used to replace/remove them. However if there are other white space characters then look at other approaches to clean up the string - see `NSString`, `NSCharacterSet`, `NSRegularExpression` etc.

HTH